# Module image not found React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am having trouble locating the location of my images with react redux.

I am creating a react movie card that looks like this:

```
http://react-movie-cards.drminnaar.me/
```

My state is in the redux store.

My file structure is this.

[image: file structure]

the state is located at  MovieList-reducer.js and I mapped it at MovieCard.js file.

why is it having an error like this:

```
   ×
←→1 of 6 errors on the page
Error: Cannot find module '../images/Kingsglaive_Final_Fantasy_XV.jpg'
▶ 32 stack frames were collapsed.
```

and have this in the terminal:

```
    ./src/Movies/MovieCard.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

Please help me locate the file of the images.

you can find and clone my repo in https://github.com/bradrar/movie-cards and **yarn start** or **npm start**

I just need to locate the images and map it like so:

```
<img className="card-img-top"  src={require(props.movie.imageUrl)} alt="" />
```

I know I am very close because I tried

```
 <img className="card-img-top"  src={require("../images/Ghost_In_The_Shell_2_0.jpg")} alt="" />
```

and it looks like this:

[image: ghost in a shell]

Comment: You can't do like this. As you are building for the web the `require` can't be an expression as Webpack needs to statically resolve your dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my pull request [here](https://github.com/bradrar/movie-cards/pull/1/commits/adc772b1be98c4bee83f367bd6c5f8673e5159f6). Because webpack needs to know all your dependencies at build time, it's not possible to use require in a dynamic context. Use [`require.context()`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context) to build a context of all your images, and then reference them using that context.

First, change your references to use `./` instead (As because we're loading that folder into context, that essentially becomes the root `./`):

```
{
    "id": 100,
    "title": "Kingsglaive",
    ...
    "imageUrl": "./Kingsglaive_Final_Fantasy_XV.jpg"
},
```

And then in your movie card, create the context. (React will read through the folder at build time, and then give you the ability to access them using the context created):

```
const movieImages = require.context("../images/", true, /\.jpg$/);

const MovieCard = (props) => {
    return (      
        ...
        <img className="card-img-top" src={movieImages(props.movie.imageUrl)} alt="" />
    )
}
```

Comment: Wow! thank you very much. `require.context` is new to me. I think it's time I should learn webpack. Again, thank you!

Comment: Quick question. How did you know that I need to use dependency management like `require.context`?
Did you know it because you saw the `Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression` sign? or because of something else? I want to know because if this problem ever come up again, I won't to ask anybody and waste anyone's time.

Comment: @bradrar What do you mean? You were using `require()` in your source post, so I assumed you wanted to build them as dependencies.

Comment: When you get "Module not found" errors, they all point back to webpack dependencies.

Comment: I used `require()` because that is the answer in stack-overflow that works when I needed to put images via react.js. I am new to react so sorry if it doesn't make sense

Comment: "Module not found" . Okay. Got it. Thank you for sharing your knowledge.